# Typescript - Can I define the type of mixed objects without going over each property separately?

Tags: typescript

I have an array colors. for must colors I store just one value, but for the gray color I store an array of colors from white to black.

```
export const COLORS = {
   GREEN_BACKGROUND: "#00d8ae",
   GREEN_TEXT: "#038c72",
   BLUE: "#162044",
   GRAYS: Array.from(Array(15).keys()).map(
      (_, i) => {
         const brightness = 16 * (1 + i)
         return `rgb(${brightness}, ${brightness}, ${brightness})`
       },
   ),
}
```

I'm looking for a shorthand defining such object's type. If we did not have the Grays array, we could do:

```
interface IColors = {
    [k:string] : string
}
```

But trying

```
interface IColors {
    [k:string] : string
    Grays: string[]   
}
```

yields an error because the Grays object doesn't follow the rule set in the line above.

Is there currently a way to write such a type without defining each property's type separately? 
We can of course use a union type

```
interface IColors {
    [k:string] : string | string[]
}
```

But this will widen the type of the individual colors, and prevent us from passing COLOR.blue fro example as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this question has already been answered elsewhere but my search powers are not great enough.  There is currently no perfect solution for you.  Here are possible ways to proceed:

- The index signature with a union type is simple and type-safe, but as you noted, is wider than the type you're trying to describe.
- You could use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) type like this:

  ```
  type IColors = {[k: string]: string} & {GRAYS: string[]};
  declare const COLORS: IColors;
  const str = COLORS.PURPLE; // string
  const arr = COLORS.GRAYS; // string[]
  ```

  This will work for you when you read from `COLORS`, but not when you write to it.  This intersection type is relatively simple, but not type-safe.  Specifically your code above will give you an error:

  ```
  // Property 'GRAYS' is incompatible with index signature.
  const COLORS: IColors = { ... }
  ```

  and you have to work around it with something like `Object.assign()`:

  ```
  // okay
  const COLORS: IColors = Object.assign({
    GREEN_BACKGROUND: "#00d8ae",
    GREEN_TEXT: "#038c72",
    BLUE: "#162044"
  }, {
      GRAYS: Array.from(Array(15).keys()).map(
        (_, i) => {
          const brightness = 16 * (1 + i)
          return `rgb(${brightness}, ${brightness}, ${brightness})`
        },
      ),
  });
  ```
- You could give up on the index signature and use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) type to represent the exact concept of "a bunch of `string` properties unless the key is `"GRAYS"`, in which case it's a `string[]` property"... along with a helper function to infer the generic type of your constant `COLORS`:

  ```
  type IColors<K extends keyof any> = { [P in K]: P extends "GRAYS" ? string[] : string }
  const asIColors = <T extends IColors<keyof T>>(
    iColors: T) => iColors;

  const COLORS = asIColors({
    GREEN_BACKGROUND: "#00d8ae",
    GREEN_TEXT: "#038c72",
    BLUE: "#162044",
    GRAYS: Array.from(Array(15).keys()).map(
      (_, i) => {
        const brightness = 16 * (1 + i)
        return `rgb(${brightness}, ${brightness}, ${brightness})`
      },
    ),
  });
  ```

  This is arguably mostly correct and type safe, but really not simple.  And any function that accepts such a type needs to be generic so it can infer the keys.
- You could abandon this hybrid type entirely and bend to TypeScript's will instead of the reverse.  You'll probably ultimately be happier:

  ```
  interface IColors {
    individualStrings: { [k: string]: string };
    GRAYS: string[];
  }

  const COLORS: IColors = {
    individualStrings: {
      GREEN_BACKGROUND: "#00d8ae",
      GREEN_TEXT: "#038c72",
      BLUE: "#162044"
    },
    GRAYS: Array.from(Array(15).keys()).map(
      (_, i) => {
        const brightness = 16 * (1 + i)
        return `rgb(${brightness}, ${brightness}, ${brightness})`
      },
    ),
  };
  ```

  Yes, it's not the same structure, but it's simple enough, type safe, and easy to use.

Which one of those, if any, you want to use is up to you and your use case.  Hope that helps; good luck!